# Create a file that is visible in Windows Explorer

Tags: android

When I media-sync my phone to my computer via USB tethering, I am able to look into my phone's internal storage.

[image]

I'm trying to do what other apps do-- create a folder where the user can drag and drop things from their window explorer onto their desktop. (Also, I do not want to save it onto external storage, such as an SD card.)

In my scenario, I want to write and export a text file, but whenever I do export it, it ends up in the data/data directory. And that's not visible in the Windows Explorer.

**UPDATE :**

Taking Daniel Bo's suggestion, I've tried this :

```
public void exportFile(Context context){

    File filePath = context.getExternalFilesDir(null);
    File file = new File(filePath, "TestFile");

    try {
        FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fileStream.close();
        Log.d("File", "File is located at " + filePath);
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The Log says the file is located at

```
/storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.myProject.FileExporter/files
```

But when I look into my Android/data folder, it isn't there. The folder doesn't exist.

Comment: show the code that generates a reference to the storage space you are using. i assume you are wrting to internal storage, when u need to use the sdcard. even tho your phone may not have an sdcar, thats the folder you are able to see in explorer.

Comment: okay, now fire up adb shell, and check the relative position of your current folder, to the place you what to go. In your code take the relative navigation. I would check this, but I dont have an android device atm :D